# What is the difference between items and properties in jsonschema?

Tags: jsonschema

I'm just learning [`jsonschema`](http://json-schema.org). It's not clear to me what the difference is between `items` and `properties`. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`items` is for validating arrays, `properties` is for validating objects.

The value of `items` must be a JSON Schema object or an array JSON Schema objects (let's ignore if it's an array for now). The array that the `items` key word is applicable to, passes validation if all items in that array validate against the schema.

The value of `properties` must be an object. Each value in the object must be a json schema. The schemas in the object are applied to the instance object when the keys match.

Comment: There are some updated resources for learning at json-schema.org/learn/ - You may also join the official slack channel if you have any questions which fall outside of those acceptable on SO.

Comment: I've visited json-schema.org/learn and have spent some time there. I must have missed the discussion about `items` and `properties`. You are already being helpful on the slack channel. Thanks!